# How to Create a Daily Sum of Records from a table with start and end fields in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series

I have the following table

```
startdate   enddate activity
1/1/2015    1/3/2015    foo
1/2/2015    1/6/2015    bar
1/4/2015    1/7/2015    bar
```

How do i query to get the following daily sum?

```
date    foo bar
1/1/2015    1   0
1/2/2015    1   1
1/3/2015    0   1
1/4/2015    0   2
1/5/2015    0   2
1/6/2015    0   1
1/7/2015    0   0
```

i'm using PSQL if that helps.

I'm assuming this is an easy question but i can't seem to find answer when i search. Perhaps i'm not using the right terminology to describe. thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

You can use `generate_series()` and aggregation.  So, something like:

```
select dte,
       sum((activity = 'foo')::int) as foo,
       sum((activity = 'bar')::int) as bar
from (select generate_series(startdate, enddate, interval '1 day') as dte,
             activity
      from t
     ) t
group by dte
order by dte;
```

Note that `generate_series()` is highly Postgres-specific.  It is, however, highly convenient for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

We can make it more dynamic by generating more activity cases.

With reference from `Gordon Linoff's` answer , I have created postgresql function which can make it more dynamic for activity cases.

Check following function:

```
create or replace function  sp_test()
returns void as
$$

declare cases character varying;
declare sql_statement text;
begin



select string_agg(distinct concat('sum((activity=','''',activity,'''',' )::int) as ',activity,' '),',') into cases from your_tbl;

drop table if exists temp_data;

sql_statement=concat('create temporary table temp_data as select t.dte, ',cases,'from 
(select generate_series(startdate, enddate, interval ','''1 day''',') as dte,
         activity
      from your_tbl) as t group by t.dte order by t.dte');

execute sql_statement;


end;
$$
language 'plpgsql';
```

**Function uses temporary table to store dynamic columns data.**

Call function in following way to get data:

```
select * from sp_test(); select * from temp_data;
```